# $ci = new $class() takes 2 minutes to load in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

My website is in CodeIgnitor.
After sometime, it is not loading on production server.
I found some problem in **system/core/Codeignioter.php** file.

If i put die before this line then it comes.

```
$CI = new $class();
```

But if i put after this line, then its loading and loading.

I have changed php 7.3 to php 8.0, but nothing works.

I have changed mysqli to mysql, but it also not works.

My default controller is Home_controller.php and class is as below

```
class Home_controller extends Home_Core_Controller
{
}
```

Comment: Codeigniter v3.x? update your framework package by Composer. If I'ts not hepled, then explain class autoloader - maybe you override framework code by `MY_*` classes.

Comment: version is 3.1.11.
what to do ?

Comment: you use Composer? you need update framework if it's not helped, then public your bootstrap.

Comment: i downloaded codeigniter 3.1.11 now and replaced system folder.
now i will get blank page after $CI = new $class();
its not loading and loading.
before this, site loads after 2 min.
now i got blank page

Comment: then public your bootstrap
- dont understand. Can you explain

Comment: public your `application/config` and `index.php`. add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at begin of `index.php` and explain error logs

Comment: i have added error_reporting(E_ALL) but still blank page
add these files are already public
Now in CI_Controller file

after this line

    $this->load->initialize();

die() not comes

Comment: post your config and index here or on github

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/07bvlps3o6kbrkwrn58ku/Document.docx?dl=0&rlkey=p84uxg0ly0fpf9ct3f4b0138e

i have shared both files